# conversion from 'double' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data

Tags: c++, c, double, dword

I have added a resource in my project. Its size is 4.096 byte.
i need to assign it to DWORD because 3rd argument of WriteFile() needs it.

```
WriteFile(hFile, pExeResource,size, &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

So i cast it like this:

UPDATE2:   DWORD bootsize = 4096; //and still warns me
But i get this warning. can you plesae help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a combination of regional/language differences along with C-syntax.

I assume you mean `4.096` to be `4,096` with a comma separator. (Due to regional/language differences, you probably use `.` instead of `,`.)

In C/C++, you don't use the separators. Just do this instead:

```
DWORD bootsize = (DWORD)4096;
```

Comment: Are you doing this in any other places? The correction I gave above should not be giving any warnings.

Comment: Can you update the question with the new code that shows this?

Comment: You still have the period `.` there. You need to remove it.

Comment: Sure. maybe i should suppress warnings somehow. thank you very much

Comment: No, don't suppress the warning. If you cast `4.096` to an integer, the value will be rounded down to `4`! I assume you want `4096`. In which case, get rid of the `.`: `DWORD bootsize = 4096;`

Comment: sorry i pasted the old line the . isnt there any more but i still get warned. nevermind thank you all.

Comment: Suppressing warnings won't help. Fixing your code is the solution.

Comment: Yes you are right. i ll see it again tomorrow with clear head. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`4.096` is a floating point value (of type `double`), just less than 4.1, while `DWORD` is an integral type (usually something like an `unsigned int`). Naturally you lose the fractional part of the floating-point value in the conversion. (Perhaps you meant the *integer* value `4096` (no punctuation)?)

Answer (score 2):

`4.096` is four and 96/1000ths of a byte.  I think you just want `4096`.  Then you don't have to cast.  Typically you don't use a comma or period in numbers in programming unless you really mean it as a decimal point.

Comment: DWORD bootsize = 4.096;
No error but same warning so it cant compile